# boost bimap and multi_index_container debugger visualizer for 2013

Tags: c++, visual-c++, boost

We plan to use boost bimap and multi_index_container

We would like to watch the container's value when running in vs2013 debugger.

I couldn't find debug visualizers for these containers though. There is: [boost multiprecision debugger visualizer](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/multiprecision/doc/html/boost_multiprecision/tut/misc/visualizers.html) but it (obviously) doesn't not support these containers.

Does anybody know where these can be found if they exist?

Answer (score 1):

https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/wiki/DebuggerVisualizers lists the some of the existing visualizers.

It mentions bimap and multi_index_container. You will probably need to check which versions of Visual Studio they are compatible with.

Comment: https://svn.boost.org/svn/boost/sandbox/boost_docs/subprojects/DebuggerVisualizers/ .  i select bimap to test that site and paste the bimap debugging expression to autoexp.bat but it's not work on vs 2013.